# How can i backup and Azure DB to local disk?

Tags: powershell, azure-sql-database

I have tried using the option Export Data-tier option but I get errors in all outputs
Exporting Database
Extracting Schema
Extracting Schema from database

and there are no details about why it failed.\
Is there a way I can back it up on Azure and copy the bacpac file or with powershell ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the backup the database to Blob Storage on Portal, then download it to your local disk.
[image]

For Powershell, here's the Command example: Backup SQL Azure database to local disk only:

```
C:\PS>Backup-Database -Name “database1” -DownloadLocation “D:\temp” -Server “mydatabaseserver” -UserName “username”  -Password “password” -Verbose
```

For more details, reference [Backup SQL Azure Database](http://blog.cerebrata.com/backup-sql-azure-database/).

Here's a tutorial [How to backup Azure SQL Database to Local Machine](https://sqlbackupandftp.com/blog/how-to-backup-azure-sql-database-to-local-machine) talks about almost all the ways to help you backup the Azure SQL Database to local disk:
[image]
[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can use SqlPackage to create a backup (export a bacpac) of your Azure SQL Database in your local drive.

```
sqlpackage.exe /Action:Export /ssn:tcp:sqlftpbackupserver.database.windows.net /sdn:sqlftpbackupdb /su:alberto /tf:c:\sql\sqlftpbackup.bacpac /sp:yourpwd /p:Storage=File
```

In above example, we are exporting a file (Export) to an Azure SQL Server named sqlftpbackupserver.database.windows.net and the source database name is sqlftpbackup. The source user is alberto and the target file where we will export is in the c:\sql\sqlftpbackup.bacpac sp is to specify the Azure SQL database password of the Azure SQL user. Finally, we will store in a file.

Another example is:

```
SqlPackage /Action:Export /SourceServerName:SampleSQLServer.sample.net,1433 
/SourceDatabaseName:SampleDatabase /TargetFile:"F:\Temp\SampleDatabase.bacpac"
```